# TypeScript - how to prevent overwriting class methods with variables in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tslint

I have a large code base where some class members are set twice - once as a method, and the other explicitly in the constructor.

Here is a an example of what this might look like:

```js
class SuperHero {
    public name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;

        // This line is a problem.
        this.hasCape = () => {
            return this.name === 'Batman';
        };
    }

    // I want this to be the canonical implementation.
    public hasCape() {
        return this.name === 'Batman' || this.name === 'Wonder Woman';
    }
}
```

It looks like `public readonly hasCape()` is invalid syntax.

Is there a way to enforce the method declaration as canonical at the compiler or linter level?

Comment: It is actually common practice to enforce overwriting all class methods in the constructor instead, for performance. Often times you will see
`this.hasCape = this.hasCape.bind(this)`

Comment: You can use `public readonly hasCape = () => { ... }` but you can still overwrite it from the constructor, surprisingly. It only prevents overwriting from outside.

Comment: You can assign to any `readonly` member in the constructor.  At least using Aaron's syntax prevents a method from accidentally overwriting the method later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the comment from [Aaron Beall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225281/aaron-beall). This makes hasCape a property, that's a function, that's readonly. The typescript compiler then throws an error when assigning it from the constructor.

```
    public get hasCape() {
        return () => this.name === 'Batman' || this.name === 'Wonder Woman';
    }
```

Comment: I like this a lot, thanks! Accepting in lieu of a solution that works for functions that accept arguments.

Comment: This isn't helpful for the general case because you can't prevent methods that take parameters from being overwrriten.

Comment: Do you have an example? I think it should work for functions/methods that accept arguments/parameters just as well, like: ```public get hasCape() {         return (arg1) => this.name === 'Batman' || this.name === 'Wonder Woman' || arg1;    }```